# Exoplayer unknown source android java

Tags: java, android, rtsp, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

I integrated the code from this repo into my app:
https://github.com/kardelencanoglu/ExoPlayerRTSP
And I'm able to see the compile, and see the player on my android app in the emulator.

On my local machine I generate a rtsp stream this way, that I can recover from VLC:

`/Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC -I dummy blabla.mp4 --sout '#rtp{sdp=rtsp://0.0.0.0:8082/live}' --no-sout-all --sout-keep`

in my app build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.19.1'
```

Included:

```
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.MediaItem;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.SimpleExoPlayer;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.MediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaSource;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.ui.PlayerView;
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSourceFactory;
```

in my main activity I have:

```
   private SimpleExoPlayer player;
   private PlayerView playerView;
```

....

playerView = findViewById(R.id.player_view);

```
try {
            
            // Overriding rtspStreamUrl for testing purposes
            rtspStreamUrl = "rtsp://10.0.2.2:8082/live";
            Uri videoUri = Uri.parse(rtspStreamUrl);

            player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();
            playerView.setPlayer(player);
            MediaSource mediaSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this, "exoplayer-codelab")).createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(videoUri));
            player.prepare(mediaSource);
            player.setPlayWhenReady(true);
            playerView.bringToFront();
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Unable to start EXO player","");
        }
```

I get the following error in logcat:

Playback error
c*om.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:684)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:656)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.HttpDataSource$HttpDataSourceException: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: rtsp
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:388)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:269)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:90)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1013)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:420)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
**Caused by: java.net.MalformedURLException: unknown protocol: rtsp**
at java.net.URL.(URL.java:608)
at java.net.URL.(URL.java:498)
at java.net.URL.(URL.java:447)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.makeConnection(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:530)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultHttpDataSource.open(DefaultHttpDataSource.java:382)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.DefaultDataSource.open(DefaultDataSource.java:269) 
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.StatsDataSource.open(StatsDataSource.java:90) 
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ProgressiveMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ProgressiveMediaPeriod.java:1013) 
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:420) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:644) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012) *

Any idea would be much appreciated, thanks in advance!

I tried to retrieve the stream in VLC, it works all fine, but not in emulator.

**EDIT:**
the problem changes if I do:

```
import com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.rtsp.RtspMediaSource;
```

and instead of Progressive I use:

```
MediaSource mediaSource =
                    new RtspMediaSource.Factory().createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(rtspStreamUrl));
```

then I get:
Playback error
com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlaybackException: Source error
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleIoException(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:684)
at com.google.android.exoplayer2.ExoPlayerImplInternal.handleMessage(ExoPlayerImplInternal.java:660)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:205)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:294)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:67)
Caused by: com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.rtsp.RtspMediaSource$RtspPlaybackException: SETUP 461